# nginx and local php.ini

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I got a server with a few different domains on. Server is running ubuntu 18.04, php 7.4-fpm.
My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set a local php.ini file for each domain, in case I need to change a few local variables.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a php.ini file in each of the domain's document roots.  For example, in public_html or any other document root, you can use a text editor to create and save a php.ini file, or from the command line type `touch php.ini` to create the file.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and no effect, so I was thinking I might need to point to this file in the sites nginx configuration file.